# One sided limit of an increasing function defined on an open interval

Tags: functions, limits

Let $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ be a strictly increasing function. Does the limit $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$ necessarily exist and is a real number or $-\infty$?  If so, is it true that $\ell=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\le f(x) \ \ \forall x\in (a,b)$? Please provide proofs.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: No. So far I am convinced that the answer to both questions is yes and tried to prove the second one. Suppose that $\exists x_0\in (a,b):f(x_0)<\ell$. Then, $\exists \xi>0:a<x_0-\xi<x_0<x_0+\xi<b$ and so $f(x_0)<f(x_0+\xi)$. I tried $\epsilon=f(x_0+\xi)-f(x_0)$ to get a contradiction but I can't show that.

Comment: I have reached this point: $\exists \delta>0:0<x-a<\delta\Rightarrow f(x_0)<\ell+(f(x_0+\xi)-f(x))$. If is show that $\exists x\in (a,b): 0<x-a<\delta\wedge x>x_0-\xi$ I am done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both statements are true.

There are two cases to consider. Let $S=\{f(x):x\in(a,b)\}$. Suppose first that $S$ is bounded below, i.e., that there is some $y\in\Bbb R$ such that $y<f(x)$ for all $x\in(a,b)$. Then by the completeness of $\Bbb R$ the set $S$ has a greatest lower bound (or infimum) $u$. I claim that $\lim\limits_{x\to a^+}f(x)=u$.

To prove this, let $\epsilon>0$. Then $u+\epsilon>u$, so $u+\epsilon$ is not a lower bound of $S$, and there is therefore some $a+\delta\in(a,b)$ such that $f(a+\delta)<u+\epsilon$. But $f$ is strictly increasing, so $$u\le f(x)<f(a+\delta)<u+\epsilon$$ for every $x\in(a,a+\delta)$, and therefore $\lim\limits_{x\to a^+}f(x)=u$.

The second is an immediate consequence of the argument just given: $u\le f(x)$ for every $x\in(a,b)$.

Now suppose that $S$ is not bounded below. Then for every $u\in\Bbb R$ there is an $x_u\in(a,b)$ such that $f(x_u)<u$. Since $f$ is strictly increasing, we have $f(x)<f(x_u)<u$ for every $x\in(a,x_u)$, and it now follows easily that $\lim\limits_{x\to a^+}f(x)=-\infty$.

Comment: You say that $u=\inf S$ and then that $u$ is not a lower bound of $S$. Do you mean $u+\epsilon$?

Comment: @SomeoneContinuous: Yes, that was a typo. I also still have to add the other case.

Comment: At the second line, didn't you mean $u\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Actually it follows that $l=\lim_{x\to a} f(x)<f(x) \quad \forall \, x\in (a,b),$ provided $f$ is strictly increasing on the open interval $(a,b).$

Comment: @azc: True, but I was addressing the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

As for the second statement, I think there is a more precise result. Below is my trial, please check if it is correct.

**Lemma** *Let $f\colon D\subset\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}.$ Suppose that $a, b\in D$ with $a<b, $ and the point $a$ is a right-sided limit point of $D.$     Let $f$ is   strictly increasing on $(a,b)\cap D.$ If  $f$ has a  right limit $f(a+0)$ at $a,$ then 
    \begin{gather*}
  f(x)>f(a+0),\qquad\forall x\in (a,b)\cap D.
 \end{gather*}*

**Proof:**
    Let $A=f(a+0):=\lim\limits_{x\to a+0}f(x).$
    If $A=-\infty,$ then there is nothing to show. So we assume that $A\in\mathbb{R}.$

We prove the statement by contradiction. If otherwise there exists $x_1\in (a,b)\cap D$ such that 
    $f(x_1)<A,$ then, for $\epsilon_1=\frac{A-f(x_1)}{2},$ there exists $\delta_1>0$ with $\delta<x_1-a,$ such that for all $x\in (a,b)\cap D,$ if $0<a-x<\delta_1,$ then 
    \begin{gather*}
  f(x)>A-\epsilon_1=A-\frac{A-f(x_1)}{2}=\frac{A+f(x_1)}{2}>f(x_1).
 \end{gather*}
    Pick $y_1\in (a,a+\delta_1),$ then $a<y_1<a+\delta_1<a+x_1-a=x_1,$ and $f(y_1)>f(x_1).$ But this contradicts that $f$ is strictly increasing on $(a,b)\cap D.$ If otherwise there also exists $x_2\in (a,b)\cap D$ such that $f(x_2)=A,$ then, pick arbitrarily $x_3\in (a,x_2),$ then, by strict increasingness of $f$ on $(a,b)\cap D,$ we have $f(x_3)<f(x_2)=A.$ By what we have proved, a contradiction also occurs. Therefore we have proved that $f(x)>f(a+0),$ for all $x\in (a,b)\cap D.$