# Prove that $f(x_n^+)-f({x_n}^-)=2^{-n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $x_n$ be an enumeration of $\Bbb Q\cap (0,1)$.

Let $\Omega_x=\{n: x_n<x\}$.

Let $$f:(0,1)\to \Bbb R\\f(x)=\sum_{n\in\Omega_x}2^{-n}$$

Prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to x_n^+} f(x)-\lim\limits_{x\to x_n^-}f(x)=2^{-n}$. I've been trying useless stuff such as writing the limits as $f(x+h), h\to 0$, trying to rewrite the sets in any useful manner, but there's no case, I couldn't solve this.

Could anyone give me some hints to head for the right direction?

Comment: Is $x_n$ (i.e. in the limits) just some arbitrary element of $\Omega_x$?

Comment: @Math1000 Yes. ${}$

Comment: $$\lim\limits_{x\to z^+} f(x)=\sum_k2^{-k}\,[x_k\leqslant z]\qquad\lim\limits_{x\to z^-}f(x)=\sum_k2^{-k}\,[x_k< z]$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $f$ is an increasing function, so the limits are well-defined.

Fix $n\in \mathbb N$.

Let  $m\in \mathbb N$ be arbitrary.

Note that  $\displaystyle f(x_n+\frac1m)-f(x_n-\frac1m)=\sum_{k\in \Omega_{x_n+\frac1m}\setminus\Omega_{x_n-\frac1m}} 2^{-k}$.

Let $A_m=\Omega_{x_n+\frac1m}\setminus\Omega_{x_n-\frac1m}=\{k, x_k\in \mathbb Q\cap [x_n-\frac1m, x_n+\frac1m(\}$.

Note that $A_m$ is a decreasing sequence, and $\bigcap_mA_m=\{n\}$

Rewriting things a little, we have  $\displaystyle \sum_{k\in \Omega_{x_n+\frac1m}\setminus\Omega_{x_n-\frac1m}} 2^{-k}=2^{-n}+\sum_{k\in A_m\setminus \{n\}}2^{-k}$.

Hence $\displaystyle f(x_n+\frac1m)-f(x_n-\frac1m)=2^{-n}+\sum_{k\in A_m\setminus \{n\}}2^{-k}$.

---

It remains to prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{m\to \infty}\sum_{k\in A_m\setminus \{n\}}2^{-k}=0$ and we're done.

Since the sets  $A_m\setminus\{n\}$ are decreasing, the sequence $\displaystyle s_m:=\left(\sum_{k\in A_m\setminus \{n\}}2^{-k}\right)_m$ is decreasing, but also bounded below by $0$, hence convergent.

Now, consider the sequence $a_m=\min(A_m\setminus \{n\})$.

Since $\displaystyle \bigcap_m\left(A_m\setminus \{n\}\right)=\emptyset$ it must be that $\forall k, \exists N, \forall l\geq N, a_l\neq a_k$.

Therefore, $a_m$ is not bounded (otherwise it takes finitely many different values, and one of those values occur infinitely many times, contradicting the previous line).

Consequently, $a_m$ has a monotonic subsequence that goes to $\infty$, say $ a_{m_{p}}\to \infty$.

Finally, notice that $\displaystyle 0\leq s_{m_{p}}\leq  \sum_{k\geq a_{m_{p}} }2^{-k}$.

The sum on the right goes to $0$ as $p\to \infty$ (since it is a subsequence of the sequence $(\sum_{k\geq p} 2^{-k})_p)$.

Therefore, $s_m$ is convergent and $s_m$ has a subsequence that goes to $0$. Hence $s_m$ converges to $0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! A few questions: Why does $f$ being increasing imply that the limits are well defined? Why can you change $\lim_{x\to {x_n}^+} f(x)\mapsto \lim_{m\to+\infty} f(x_n+1/m)$?

Comment: An increasing function has one-sided limits everywhere on the interior of its domain, see this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144637/one-sided-limit-of-an-increasing-function-defined-on-an-open-interval . Since the limit exists, I'm allowed to use sequences (see sequential continuity on Google).

Answer (score -1):

This function $f(x)$ snaps to a value as $x$ hits one of the values in the enumeration, holds that value until we hit the successive value of the enumeration.  So lets focus in on a particular $x_n$ and  pick $h>0$ so that is smaller than the difference between the $n-1$ and $n$ terms AND $n$ and $n+1 $terms :
$$
x_{n}+h < x_{n+1}    \quad    (x_n,x_n+h,x_{n+1})\\
x_{n-1}+ h < x_n - h\quad      (x_{n-1}, x_{n-1} - h, ,x_n )
$$
So we can easily calculate what $f$ is for values over this range.

Now pick $k_1,k_2$ such that  $0< k_1,k_2 < h$.

Then we have for any such $k_1,k_2$, the difference between the value of the functions is just the last term of the summation $\frac 1 {2^n}$.

$$f(x_n-k_1) - f(x_n+k_2) = \frac 1 {2^n}$$

hence the result .

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand most of what you've written, could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: What I'm trying to show is that I can create a interval around xn_1 and xn where the value of f() has a stable value, so as I tighten up that interval, the value of the function takes the limiting value from above and below, hence the expression for the difference.

Comment: Please check if my edit accurately translated what you had written.

Comment: I made two small edits to the answer, I removed the dots, this to show how we choose h to so that xn+h,xn-h falls between successive xn's in the sequence - this is the crucial part of the derivation so that as h->0 we can evaluate the value of f(xn).

Comment: Caution, there is no positive $k_1$ and $k_2$ such that $f(x_n-k_1) - f(x_n+k_2) = \frac 1 {2^n}$.

Comment: I don't understand, I thought the xn's were a enumeration, so we could take k1 = |xn-xn-1|/2 and k2 = |xn+1 - xn|/2

Comment: Ok, I got it, I completely misunderstood the question - my bad...