# Let f be a real-valued monotone non-decreasing function on $\Bbb R$. Then which of following statement is true?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

Let f be a real-valued monotone non-decreasing function on $\Bbb R$. Then which of following statement is true?

1. for $a\in\Bbb R$, $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists.
2. $f$ is unbounded function.
3. $h(x)= e^{-f(x)}$ is a bounded function.
4. if $a<b$,then $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x) \leq \lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)$

To solve this question, i took $f(x)=(-1)^x$. Now is it non-decreasing/non increasing function? and with this function I crossed out statements 1,2 and 3.
Is this example perfect to take here? 
Can someone tell the general explanation, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $(-1)^x$ it is not well defined. What is $(-1)^{\pi}$?

As regards your statements:

Statement 1 can be false: take 
$$f(x)= \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        1 & \text{for } x>0\\
        0 & \text{for } x=0\\
        -1 & \text{for } x<0
        \end{array}\right.
$$
then it is monotone non-decreasing and 
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=1\quad\mbox{and}\quad\lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x)=-1$$
which means that the limit of $f$ at $0$ does not exist.

Statement 2 can be false: take $f(x)=\arctan(x)$.

Statement 3 can be false: take $f(x)=x$.

Statement 4 is true because $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=\inf_{a>x} f(x)$,  $\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)=\sup_{y<b} f(y)$ and $f(x)\leq f(y)$ fo r $x<a<b<y$ because $f$ is monotone non-decreasing.

Comment: if i take f(x) to be floor function, lim x->a still exists.is it not? Can you provide any other example for part a? And how is f(x)<=f(y) in d?

Comment: In d) $f$ is a monotone non-decreasing function. I edit my answer fo a)

Comment: @Parul Any further doubt? – Robert Z

Comment: one last doubt, how can we write this limx→a+ f(x)=supx<a f(x)?Can you provide any link where i can understand its theory?

Comment: @Parul See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144637/one-sided-limit-of-an-increasing-function-defined-on-an-open-interval

Comment: @Parul I corrected a typo in my answer for statement 4. (I swapped $\inf$ a $\sup$)

Comment: The function $(-1)^x$ is well defined if you allow it to take complex values. Since $-1 = e^{j\pi}$, we have $(-1)^x = e^{j\pi x}$.