# show that $ f $ is continuous in $a$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

If $I = [a,b] $ and suppose $f : I → R $ is increasing in $I$, then $f$ is continuous in $a$ if and only if

$f(a)$ = $inf$ $\{f(x):x ∈→ (a,b)\}$
I've solved it this way, okay? If not, please help me correct it.

Let $f$ continue en $x=a →$ lim $x_→a^+$ $f(x)=f(a)$
Let's suppose $inf\{f(x)/ x ∈ ]a,b[\}) = L ≠ f(a)→L>f(a)$

lim $_{x→a^+}$ $f(x)=f(a)→$ si $\varepsilon = \frac{f(a)-L}{2}>0, \exists \delta$ $> 0 / a<x<a + \delta →|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon →$
$|f(x)-f(a)|< \frac{f(a)-L}{2}→f(x)-f(a) <\frac{f(a)-L}{2}→ 2f(x)-2f(a)<f(a)-L→$
$f(x)<\frac{3f(a)-L}{2}→ f(x)<\frac{3f(a)-f(a)}{2}→f(x)<f(a)$ contradiction then $ x>a$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [One sided limit of an increasing function defined on an open interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144637/one-sided-limit-of-an-increasing-function-defined-on-an-open-interval)

Comment: I'm finding this really hard to read, but it *looks* like you have successfully proven one direction: that if $f$ is continuous at $a$, then $\inf\{f(x) : x \in (a, b)\} = f(a)$. What's missing is the proof of the converse: if $\inf\{f(x) : x \in (a, b)\} = f(a)$, then $f$ is continuous at $a$.

Comment: but in the final part it is not proven? If not, then I need you to please help me.

Answer (score 1):

For the converse, suppose $\inf\{f(x) : x \in (a, b)\} = f(a)$. Fix $\varepsilon > 0$. Note that $f(a) + \varepsilon$ is **not** a lower bound for $\{f(x) : x \in (a, b)\}$, as it is greater than the greatest lower bound $f(a)$. Hence, there must exist some $c \in (a, b)$ such that $f(a) \le f(c) < f(a) + \varepsilon$.

Now, because $f$ is increasing, we know that, for any $x \in [a, c)$,
\begin{align*}
f(a) \le f(x) \le f(c) < f(a) + \varepsilon &\implies 0 \le f(x) - f(a) < \varepsilon \\
&\implies |f(x) - f(a)| = f(x) - f(a) < \varepsilon.
\end{align*}
So, if we choose $\delta = c - a > 0$, then
$$0 \le x - a < \delta \implies a \le x < c \implies |f(x) - f(a)| < \varepsilon,$$
i.e. $\lim_{x \to a^+} f(x) = f(a)$, i.e. $f$ is continuous at $a$.

Comment: ok, this way is concluded? I am studying for an exam, thanks for the help ..

Comment: Yes, combine this with your answer, and we have a full "if and only if" proof of the problem.